# Enable timezone on FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm rebuilding an existing project in which I need to have timezone support. The events get rendered fine by a json-feed. Example data:

```
[{
    "id":"1",
    "title":"Titel",
    "start":"2016-10-08T12:00:00+02:00",
    "end":"2016-10-08T12:30:00+02:00",
}]
```

As you see the event has Timezone-Data. (`2016-10-08T12:00:00+02:00`)

I want to use `eventDrop` to update an event, an when the user drags and drops an event, the data (eventId, start_time, end_time) is sent to the PHP, which updates the database.

My PHP-script should convert the received start_time & end_time to UTC and write it to the database.

The issue is that fullcalendar doesn't pass the timezone of the event to my PHP.
I tried passing something like:

```
event_start: moment(event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH.mm:ssZZ"),
```

The data I get is something like:

```
event_start: 2016-10-08 12.00:00+0000
```

And I expected it would be something like:

```
event_start: 2016-10-11 12.00:00+0200
```

With the timezone-information I could easily convert it to UTC.

How can I have access to the timezone on the PHP side?

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the [`timezone`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/) property, probably to 'UTC'. So, something like:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: [{
            "id":"1",
            "title":"Title",
            "start":"2016-10-08T12:00:00+02:00",
            "end":"2016-10-08T12:30:00+02:00"
        }],
        timezone: 'UTC'
    });
```

After that, when you retrieve the events, you should see a `tzm: 120` on the `start` of each event and should be able to grab the correct timezone on server side.

I've created [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/milz/k4c308so/) with a button that retrieves the events and where you can verify this.

---

Okay, if you want to get the datetime as it is you have two options:

1. Set the `timezone` property to the local you need. For instance, if you're using a `00:00+02:00`, you could set the timezone to `timezone: 'Europe/Belgrade'`
2. Just don't set the `timezone` at all (leave it to the default `false`)

Then you can get the the datetime with `event.start.format()`. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/milz/k4c308so/5/) for a demo.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.
I think I also tried to set the timezone property, but look at your fiddle:
The time on Event in the calendar is showing 10:00 (UTC). It should Show 12:00?

Comment: @Walhalla Check the updated answer. I think that's what you need. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am some steps further. It is a bit confusing. I think the TZ should be set to users TZ string like "Europe/Belgrade". When the this Option is set, then FC passes this Information automatically via json request.
When switching the TZ dynamically, then the events are not getting calculated new by JS. You need to pass the timezone again to PHP, which should calculate the changed event-time(s).

At the Moment I'm struggling here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964152/eventdrop-js-help-needed-to-dynamically-change-fc-option-jsfiddle-example

Comment: But I have UTC time in the start and end properties and I would like to change it to user timezone. How do I do that ? I have save the user Timezone to the variable `var timezone = user_timeZone`

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to add my two cents.
I had similar issues, but it worked for my needs when I used:

```
timezone:"local" (I assume you could use "UTC" in your case)
```

and

```
format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX").
```